# Extracting value of a node after a certain tag

Tags: php, parsing

Tying to extract the value "Output" between spans only if the title is "ABCD (1,2)" using php. Basically, find "Output (extract Output).

Here is the section of html:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <strong title="ABCD (1,2)" class="name">ABCD (1,2):</strong>
     <div id="test1">                                
       <div class="testclass" id="test2">
         <span>Output</span>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code I like to use:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('test.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
//Some code needs to go here! 
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('strong');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just use `xpath` in this case, use a query that would select that desired element. Get that element that has that *title* and get the following div, and under it, go to the *span*:

Example (using the markup above):

```
$html = '
<div class="wrap">
    <strong title="ABCD (1,2)" class="name">ABCD (1,2):</strong>
    <div id="test1">                                
        <div class="testclass" id="test2">
            <span>Output</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
';

$search_string = 'ABCD (1,2)';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$query = "//strong[@title = '{$search_string}']/following-sibling::div/div/span";
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query($query);
if($result->length > 0) {
    echo $result->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```